# A simple implementation of Windows Phone 7.5 Text To Speech?

Tags: windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

This does not seem to exist. All that I want is a simple, up to date tutorial or guide as to how I can utilise the TTS features on Windows Phone 7.5.

Microsoft have released a tutorial for this in WP8 recently, where it is much easier to implement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use TTS speech in Windows Phone 7.5 as it was not exposed directly earlier for Windows Phone 7 devices. But You can use this Hawaii Research project

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/default.aspx

Comment: From the Hawaii FAQ: [Y]ou can use the Hawaii SDK for research, teaching, and other academic uses, free of charge. It can however not be used for any commercial applications.